# What is the mean of connection status is suspended?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

when I run the following procedure:

```
sp_who
@loginame = 'myloginname'
```

I see a number of rows with "status" = "suspended" column. What does this mean?

Also how can I avoid from this?

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: It means you haven't searched...

Comment: I found a good article about connection status: (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlsakthi/archive/2011/02/08/different-status-of-a-spid-in-sql-server-and-what-do-they-mean.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From BOL, it is "The session is waiting for an event, such as I/O, to complete."  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174313.aspx

Comment: Does this occur on exception?